# Olap exception : Mondrian XML : :No function matches signature 'Exists(<Member>, <Set>)'

Tags: mdx, olap, mondrian, saiku, xmla

if there anyone who already get this type of error:

> OlapException: XMLA provider gave exception: <SOAP-ENV:Fault> <faultcode> SOAP-ENV:Client.00HSBD01 </faultcode> <faultstring> XMLA MDX parse failed </faultstring> <faultactor> Mondrian </faultactor> <detail> <XA:error xmlns:XA="http://mondrian.sourceforge.net"> <code> 00HSBD01 </code> <desc> The Mondrian XML: Mondrian Error:No function matches signature 'Exists(<Member>, <Set>)' </desc> </XA:error> </detail> </SOAP-ENV:Fault>`.

**My architecture:** I used tomcat-server and I deploy saiku as OLAP client and mondrian as olap server on the server because I need to access to the result in XMLA format.

Actually, this work but it depends on the query. When I do some Filter this error appears.

**For example:**

I want to analyse the number of production during all year and all month for each year it works but if I want to analyse only one year with all month of that year then It's not work.

If anyone have an idea, I would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/mdx/exists-mdx?view=sql-server-2017, arguments are: Set, Set.

Try encapsulating your first argument in curly braces.